# ASP .net VB WEB application for different mobile platforms

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

i have inherited app which is coded in VB for Windows CE device. Size of elements is "hardly" set (in px) and layout for android device is really bad. 
In future we will use both - Win and Android devices.
Is there any way how to let layout for Windows device and set layout for Android? Responsive design, for example use CSS properties, when Android is connected.

Or should i edit whole layout for both  devices? What will be the best approach?

Comment: You can use CSS3 Media Queries to determine screen size, which is preferred over writing to a specific device. Also Meta tag ViewPort settings come in handy to set zoom levels and make the design a little more friendly to all devices. For Responsive design, you might look at BootStrap. It is a start to the right path.

Comment: Thank you Dr.Aron Dishno ....i was inspired by your comment. I will do it through screens resolution. Can u put your comment as answer ... i will accept it as most inspirative/helpful  answer :-)

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated!

Comment: What version of Windows CE is it targeting? Are you running the built-in IE instance on CE or using a different web-browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS3 Media Queries to determine screen size, which is preferred over writing to a specific device. Also Meta tag ViewPort settings come in handy to set zoom levels and make the design a little more friendly to all devices. For Responsive design, you might look at BootStrap. It is a start to the right path.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

and meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```